# Regex behaves differently for the same input string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to get a pdf page with a particular string and the string is:

"statement of profit or loss"

and I'm trying to accomplish this using following regex:

```
re.search('statement of profit or loss', text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

But even though the page contained this string "statement of profit or loss" the regex returned None. 
On further investigating the document, I found that the characters 'fi' in the "profit" as written in the document are more congested. When I copied it from the document and pasted it in my code it worked fine.

So, If I copy "statement of profit or loss" from document and paste it in re.search() in my code, it works fine. But if I write "statement of profit or loss" manually in my code, re.search() returns none.
How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: PDF is not a strict text document. Hence you are having difficulty in matching pattern.

Comment: It is so common with whitespaces. Replace each space with `\s+` or `\s` in the pattern.

Comment: Just FYI It is most likely you have a hard space in the input string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'congested' characters copied from your PDF are actually a *single* character: the 'fi ligature' [U+FB01: `ﬁ`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb01/index.htm).

Either it was entered as such in the source document, or the typesetting engine that was used to create the PDF, replaced the combination `f+i` by `fi`.

Combining two or more characters into a single glyph is a fairly usual operation for "nice typesetting", and is not limited to `fi`, `fl`, `ff`, and `fj`, although these are the most used combinations. (That is because in some fonts the long overhang of the `f` glyph jarringly touches or overlaps the next character.) Actually, you can have *any* amount of ligatures; some Adobe fonts use a single ligature for `Th`.

Usually this is not a problem with text extracting, because in the PDF it can be specified that certain glyphs must be decoded as a *string* of characters – the original characters. So, possibly your PDF does not contain such a definition, or the typesetting engine did not bother because the single character `ﬁ` is a valid Unicode character on itself (although it is highly advised not to use it).

You can work around this by explicitly cleaning up your text strings before processing any further:

```
text = text.replace('ﬁ', 'fi')
```

– repeat this for other problematic ligatures which have a Unicode codepoint: `ﬂ`, `ﬀ`, `ﬃ`, `ﬄ` (I possibly missed some more).